# Unable to upload JSON file to Azure Cosmos DB due to large file size

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb

I tried to upload a `JSON` file containing a list of around 5000 `JSONs` to `Azure Cosmos dB` with `Azure Migration Tool` and was able to do that. It uploaded all 5000 items.

However when I'm trying to do the same from a .NET application, using the following code, it's not uploading and the `Azure` portal is giving an error message.

**Code:**

```
public static async Task BulkImport()
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp.json");

        List<StudentInfo> lists = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StudentInfo>>(json);

        CosmosClientOptions options = new CosmosClientOptions() { ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway, AllowBulkExecution = true };
        CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(EndpointUrl, AuthorizationKey, options);

        try
        {
            Database database = await cosmosClient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(DatabaseName);
            Console.WriteLine(database.Id);
            Container container = await database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(ContainerName, "/id");
            Console.WriteLine(container.Id);
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            foreach (StudentInfo item in lists)
            {
                tasks.Add(container.CreateItemAsync(item, new PartitionKey(item.id))
                    .ContinueWith((Task<ItemResponse<FunctionInfo>> task) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Status: " + task.Result.StatusCode + "    Resource: " + task.Result.Resource.id);
                    }));
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception = " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

**Message :**

[image: Azure Portal Message]

I tried running the code with the list containing only 100 `JSONs` and it's working fine!

Please help me regarding this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you experience is a fundamental concept in Cosmos. You provision throughput (measured in RU per second) on a container and your payment is proportional this. When you exceed the provisioned throughput you will have to wait before you can access the container. The API gives you information about how long you have to wait and the C# SDK will automatically handle this error and wait for you. The message you see in the portal is for your convenience and doesn't indicate a problem. One could say that if you don't get this message once in a while you are paying too much for your throughput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an error. It is just a warning. You were trying to create documents with too many threads, which consumes too many RUs.

The Azure CosmosDB API probably implements [Throttling pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/throttling). So, when you hit the limitation, your request will be throttled.

Azure system also monitored this event, which gives you the notification on the portal. You may check the RUs you used in metrics pages. And you may increase the throughput to increase concurrency.

But, (if you do not want to increase throughput), you may consider to:

1. Upload in batches to reduce concurrency.
2. If your requests were throttled, add wait and retry policy in your code.